# Windows 10: pin window only to a specific taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I'm using multiple virtual desktops on Windows 10. Now I'd like to pin for example firefox to the taskbar on desktop 2. But the app icon is then visible on every desktop. 
Is it possible to just show it on a specific desktop instead of every desktop?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible as of Windows 10 version 1909. Virtual desktops are a game of DWM cloaking, and there is no separate preferences/settings for different virtual desktops. See [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180501-00/?p=98645).